# How can I reproduce the following finance table in r

Tags: r, dataframe, finance

I want to recreate in R the following table :
[image]

I have been provided with only these three parameters:

```
initial_deposit = 15000
contract_value = 250
closing_stock_indices = c(1000,  1002, 994,  998, 997)
```

My effort in R is this:

```
cl =c(1000,1002,994,998,997) # The closing stock indices.
re = c(0,diff(cl))
t = time(cl)
mtm = re*250 # The contract value of 250.
mb = 15000+mtm # The initial deposit of 15000.
vm = ifelse(mb>0,0,mtm)
d = data.frame(t,cl,re,mtm,mb,vm);d
```

but I cannot do the last two columns.Any help ?

Comment: Try `margin_balance <- cumsum(required_deposit + marking_to_market)`.  If I were you, I'd choose more explanatory variable names than `t` or `d` or `re`.  Also, which of your columns are "given", and which are supposed to be calculated from the "given" columns.

Comment: only the column of  closing stocks is given and the number of required deposit (not the column only the value) and the  value of the contract which is 250.

Comment: @Greg any help mate ? thanks in advance

Comment: While this could be solved iteratively, with loops and such like, it's still harder than it looks to find a clean and efficient solution.  I might have to get back to you on that.

Comment: @NikosTsiantakis, see my tidyverse strategy.  If you need baseR please drop a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do the following

```r
library(tidyverse)

initial_deposit = 15000
contract_value = 250
closing_stock_indices = c(1000,  1002, 994,  998, 997)

(seq_along(closing_stock_indices) - 1) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames('Day') %>%
  mutate(Closing_SI = closing_stock_indices,
         Daily_change = c(0, diff(Closing_SI)),
         Marking_to_market = contract_value * Daily_change,
         Margin_balance = accumulate(Marking_to_market[-1], .init = initial_deposit,
                         ~ if (.x >= initial_deposit) .x + .y else initial_deposit + .y),
         Variation_Margin = -1 * pmin(Margin_balance - initial_deposit, 0),
         REquired_Deposit = c(initial_deposit, Variation_Margin[-n()]))

  Day Closing_SI Daily_change Marking_to_market Margin_balance Variation_Margin REquired_Deposit
1   0       1000            0                 0          15000                0            15000
2   1       1002            2               500          15500                0                0
3   2        994           -8             -2000          13500             1500                0
4   3        998            4              1000          16000                0             1500
5   4        997           -1              -250          15750                0                0
```

Check on another vector

```
initial_deposit = 15000
contract_value = 250
closing_stock_indices = c(1000,  1002, 994,  998, 997, 990, 1000)

(seq_along(closing_stock_indices) - 1) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames('Day') %>%
  mutate(Closing_SI = closing_stock_indices,
         Daily_change = c(0, diff(Closing_SI)),
         Marking_to_market = contract_value * Daily_change,
         Margin_balance = accumulate(Marking_to_market[-1], .init = initial_deposit,
                         ~ if (.x >= initial_deposit) .x + .y else initial_deposit + .y),
         Variation_Margin = -1 * pmin(Margin_balance - initial_deposit, 0),
         REquired_Deposit = c(initial_deposit, Variation_Margin[-n()]))

  Day Closing_SI Daily_change Marking_to_market Margin_balance Variation_Margin REquired_Deposit
1   0       1000            0                 0          15000                0            15000
2   1       1002            2               500          15500                0                0
3   2        994           -8             -2000          13500             1500                0
4   3        998            4              1000          16000                0             1500
5   4        997           -1              -250          15750                0                0
6   5        990           -7             -1750          14000             1000                0
7   6       1000           10              2500          17500                0             1000
```

Comment: if you are not comfortable in tidyverse an equivalent baseR may be given easily.  Just ask

Comment: why for some of the lines appears the red index in the line number?

Comment: which lines? @NikosTsiantakis.  I couldn't understand.  Are the markdown language you are referring?

Comment: on your second code lines 8 , 12 ,12, 13, 14

Comment: In my IDE it isn't.  That may be the markdown format/appearance in your IDE.  Ignore that. @NikosTsiantakis

Comment: thanks for your answer I appreciate your effort and your job.thanks @AnilGoyal

Comment: Glad that it helped @NikosTsiantakis :)